# exporting a rich text field in excel

Tags: reporting

I would like to make a report of a rich text field. Unfortunately, when details are exported, the rich text is lost (linebreaks are gone for example), when opened in excel.
Is there a way to export, and keep the rich text of a field?

Answer (score 2):

As per the Salesforce document,

Rich text area fields can be filtered and summarized in reports, but HTML tags and special formatting aren’t included in report results. For example, **some** *text* becomes “some text” instead of **some** *text* or some text.

Referenced Link: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_using_rich_text_area.htm

Idea Link (Allow Rich Text fields to display (and export) properly on reports): https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bUhoAAE